# Left-hand assignment error for text-decoration

Tags: javascript, css

I don't know why this won't work on firefox, but it works on chrome. Here's my code:

```
var a = document.getElementById("link");
a.style.color = "#0000FF";
//a.style.text-decoration = "none";
```

The commented line is the error happens in firefox. I suspect it may have to do something with "-" and firefox is treating it like a subtract operator, that is what I thought. Is there any way that I can avoid firefox from treating the dash as a math operator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you're looking for is `textDecoration` :)

http://jsfiddle.net/8PEZX/

```
a.style.textDecoration = "none";
```

Most (if not all, I'm just not sure, so I'm saying most :D) hyphenated properties get changed to camelCase in JavaScript.

Also, I just tested it with `text-decoration` and it didn't work in Chrome, so not sure how yours worked.

Comment: it works, don't know why firefox treats it as a math operator, but thanks :D

Comment: Oh just made experiment based on your code. It doesn't work on chrome either, except for some reason Chrome doesn't treat it as a mandatory error, and still execute the code. On firefox, it breaks xD